# Google Script Editor Script raises yesterday's email as an email from the day before

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script-editor

Hope you are all well!

Simply put : The script I am working on counts how many emails from the29th of october are still in my inbox. It also lists all the emails presents in my inbox by date and by subject. The data is sent to a Google Sheets Spreadsheet.

```
22
Agradecemos a inscrição no programa Facebook Marketing Partners para Agências   2019-10-30  0,00
23
O desempenho do seu anúncio poderia ser muito melhor    2019-10-30  0,00
24
### iniciou trabalho na tarefa #2598 - ### B&I Diversos 2019-10-30  0,00
25
Tarefa #2598 - Início agendado! 2019-10-30  0,00
26
Analise em maior detalhe a jornada do cliente em todos os dispositivos  2019-10-30  0,00
27
Seu anúncio foi aprovado    2019-10-29  1,00
28
a faire ce soir 2019-10-30  1,00
29
2019-10-29  2,00
30
yo  2019-10-28  2,00
31
Hello, world!   2019-10-28  2,
```

As you can see email 27 appears as received on the 29th of October when it has been received yesterday(30th). 
Not sure if it is a bug or something else I am not thinking of at the moment.

Here is the code, apologize for the comments in português

```js
function emailExtract() {

// CONTAGEM DE EMAIL
// __Soma de emails que respeita a condição do If STATEMENT
  var emailCount = 0


// DADOS DE DATA
// __Variável com data do dia
  var today =  new Date();

// __Obtem a data de ontem
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;  //___________________________________24h in milliseconds to get to the same date but the day before
  var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_DAY);


// CRIAÇÃO DA TABELA-DATABASE 
// __Definição da Spreadsheet Google Sheets
  var listSpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var listSheet = listSpread.getActiveSheet();



for ( var i = 0 ; i < 20; i++) {  //_____________________________________________changed to 20 insted of 100

// DADOS DE EMAIL 
// __Obtem acesso ao email em posição i
  var getEmail = GmailApp.getInboxThreads()[i];
  var Message = getEmail.getMessages()[0];


// __Obtem dados do email, aqui : email do expeditor, data de envio
  var testMessage = Message.getSubject();
  var email = Message.getFrom();  //______________________________________________gets sender email
  var dateSent = Message.getDate();  //___________________________________________gets day and date of email reception  


// IF STATEMENT = Bate email selectionado com dia desejado
// __Formata as datas en Yesterday e dateSent, tirando hora, Min, sec. 
  var testDateYesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var testDateSent = Utilities.formatDate(dateSent, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

// __if statement e incrementação da váriavel emailCount
    if (testDateYesterday == testDateSent) {
       emailCount++;
       }
listSheet.appendRow([testMessage,testDateSent, emailCount]);

}  
}
```

Hope someone will have an idea on what is going on. Any clue would help.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it the case that  #29, #30 and #31 are also outside the parameter? My first inclination is daylight savings, though I can see that you take this into account. In any event, I would recommend looking closely at the metadata for #27 to identify the date and time sent and received.

Comment: #29 should be the only email from the 29th 
#30 #31 are right and from the 28th 
Everything else is from the 30th which brings the question : Why is email 27 shown as being received on the 29th when it was received on the 30th. 
Will check the metadata right now, good hint!

Comment: Checked, Email was created on the 30th

Comment: Well, that's good news; so the script is trustworthy.

Comment: Which means it might be...a bug from Google? 
Arf.

Comment: Hmm. I'd be looking to see where it could somehow get a value of 2019-10-29. It's not in the meta? what's the full date/time? what's the time zone? what is the senders "sent" date?